# How to make click/tap to play or pause video work the same on desktop and mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, video.js

On my site, when viewed on a desktop browser, clicking on a video will play or pause that video.  However, on mobile browsers, the behavior is very inconsistent.  Clicking or tapping on a video will only sometimes start it, and never pause it.  Oddly, this inconsistent behavior happens even when simulating a mobile browser in the desktop browser's developer mode!

**How can I get consistent click-to-play/pause behavior on all devices and platforms?**  I want a click/tap to always play a paused video, and always pause a playing video.

I am using a combination of some html5 video elements and some video elements wrapped via video.js.  I need a solution that will work for both types.  All videos show controls, if that matters.  I'm aware that there are 2 or 3 fairly similar questions on SE, but they are all very old and none have answers that appear to work in 2022.

Comment: Does it help to consider the reason the behaviour is not the same is that the controls show/hide on desktop, but a hover is not possible on mobile. Instead, the control display toggles on tap.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of alternative jquery/html5 solutions you could try https://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/Video%20Player/
but it might be worth looking at the videojs GitHub issues for some ideas on how to fix your issue https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/975

I hope this is of some help